# Use results in one column on a SQL table to search another table

Tags: sql

I was just after an elegant solution to what I'm doing rather than just manually copying and pasting into each SELECT query.

I have a list of 200+ string results from one table.

`SELECT name FROM accounts`

Which gives me results like:

| name |
| --- |
| $string1$ |
| $string2$ |

I want to then search each result in another query on another table to get a COUNT. Doing this manually one by one, I would run:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table.id) FROM table WHERE table.code LIKE '%$string1$%'`

I want to be lazy and achieve this via SQL if possible where I end up with something like this:

| accounts.name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| $string1$ | 5699 |
| $string2$ | 245 |

Any advice or help would be most welcome!

Comment: Hint: Join and aggregation...

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: This is easily done with a lateral join but the syntax varies between databases, hence you *need* to tell us the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd want to join on a LIKE operator, and then count the results:

```
  ;WITH matches_on_account_name AS (
        SELECT a.[name] AS account_name
          FROM accounts AS a
          JOIN [table] AS t ON t.[code] LIKE '%' + a.[name] + '%'
  )
  SELECT account_name,
         COUNT(*) AS num_accounts
    FROM matches_on_account_name
GROUP BY account_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option that should work on pretty much every RDBMS is a correlated subquery

```
select a.name, (
  select Count(*) 
    from table t 
    where t.code like Concat('%',a.name,'%')
) as Count
from accounts a
```

Comment: Thanks Stu - that one worked well!

Answer (score 0):

Using CONCAT for sticking the % to the name.

And defaulting the NULL names to something unmatchable.
Just preventing that `name LIKE '%%'` would match everything.

```
SELECT 
  acc.name AS account_name
, COUNT(DISTINCT tbl.id) AS total_uniq_table_id
FROM accounts  AS acc
JOIN yourtable AS tbl
  ON tbl.code LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(acc.name,'D§OUOSVAVV§M'),'%') 
GROUP BY acc.name
```

Comment: You can avoid the `coalesce()` with the "magic value", if you use `'%'||acc.name||'%'`. That will result in `null` if the name is null thus the join condition won't match.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're assuming we know what rdbms the OP uses.

Comment: Well, `||` is standard SQL, while `concat()` is not

Comment: Sql Server doesn't know ||. And oracle doesn't return null from `'abc'||null`. Concat is everywhere, except Oracle being awkward again by only accepting 2 params.